# How to get "OAuth redirect_uri" and website for Android Instagram app?

Tags: oauth, instagram

I'm new to Android development and I'm trying to develop an app which would use Instagram's API to get images with specific tags. I'm an individual developer and do not have a website. When I go to "Register new Client ID" on Instagram dedvelopers page, it asks me for a website and a OAuth redirect_uri, and I have neither. What do I put in those fields? Also, the tutorial I was trying to follow is not very helpful. Could you also point me to some helpful and easy to follow tutorial/s which would help me do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I'd the similar doubt and here I found a link for this, which explaining everything we need to know at the time of registering an app in Instagram.

https://thechamplord.wordpress.com/2014/04/14/how-to-configure-instagram-application-and-get-client-id/

For a future perspective, I'm adding the actual answer so that if in case link will go in crash then our answer wouldn't break.

- Website: It can be your website name (product website or even a webpage link). Please make sure that this url includes http:// or https:// and there is no trailing slash (for example: http://mywebsite.com or http://www.mywebsite.com)
- OAuth redirect_uri : It would be same values as you've entered for website.

Comment: I have same problem but how we set OAuth redirect_uri ? i'm using android WebView to authorize user but how i can access token ? what i must set on the redirect_uri  ? i dont have a redirect_uri  i want save token inside app?